# Why List<LinkedList<String>> do not work?

Tags: java, list, linked-list

I am having problem with `List<LinkedList<String>>`.
printPath method is printing a Linked list of string but it is not going into favp.
Please help me. Any clue,link,reference will be appreciable.
Thank you.

```
private List<LinkedList<String>> favp = new ArrayList<LinkedList<String>>();
 private void printPath(LinkedList<String> visited) {
    favp.add(visited);
    for (String node : visited) {
        System.out.print(node);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

private void printFavp() {
    for (LinkedList<String> ls : favp) {
        for (String s : ls) {
            System.out.print("-->" + s);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

EDIT:
visited is a linked list of String.
I am printing it on console by printPath() method.
Side by side I am trying to put the linked list of String i.e. `visited` into `favp`.
I have made printFavp() method to print the values in it.
Thanks.

EDIT 2:
This is Graph.java

```
package search;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Search {

    private static final String START = "C1";
    private static final String END = "C5";
    private static final int STOP = 5;
    private List<LinkedList<String>> favp = new ArrayList<LinkedList<String>>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // this graph is directional
        Graph graph = new Graph();
        graph.addEdge("C1", "C2");
        graph.addEdge("C1", "C4");
        graph.addEdge("C2", "C3");
        graph.addEdge("C3", "C1");
        graph.addEdge("C1", "C5");
        graph.addEdge("C3", "C4");
        graph.addEdge("C3", "C5");
        graph.addEdge("C4", "C5");
        graph.addEdge("C5", "C2");
        LinkedList<String> visited = new LinkedList<String>();
        visited.add(START);
        Search s = new Search();
        s.breadthFirst(graph, visited);
        s.printFavp();
    }

    private void breadthFirst(Graph graph, LinkedList<String> visited) {
        LinkedList<String> nodes = graph.adjacentNodes(visited.getLast());
        // examine adjacent nodes
        for (String node : nodes) {
            if (visited.contains(node)) {
                continue;
            }
            if (node.equals(END)) {
                visited.add(node);
                System.out.print("----->");
                printPath(visited);
                visited.removeLast();
                break;
            }
        }
        // in breadth-first, recursion needs to come after visiting adjacent
        // nodes
        for (String node : nodes) {
            if (visited.contains(node) || node.equals(END)) {
                continue;
            }
            visited.addLast(node);
            int stop = STOP + 2;
            if (visited.size() < stop)
                breadthFirst(graph, visited);
            visited.removeLast();
        }
    }

    private void printPath(LinkedList<String> visited) {
        favp.add(visited);
        for (String node : visited) {
            System.out.print(node);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    private void printFavp() {
        for (LinkedList<String> ls : favp) {
            for (String s : ls) {
                System.out.print("-->" + s);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

This is Search.java

```
package search;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class Graph {
    private Map<String, LinkedHashSet<String>> map = new HashMap<String, LinkedHashSet<String>>();

    public void addEdge(String node1, String node2) {
        LinkedHashSet<String> adjacent = map.get(node1);
        if(adjacent==null) {
            adjacent = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
            map.put(node1, adjacent);
        }
        adjacent.add(node2);
    }

    public void addTwoWayVertex(String node1, String node2) {
        addEdge(node1, node2);
        addEdge(node2, node1);
    }

    public boolean isConnected(String node1, String node2) {
        Set<?> adjacent = map.get(node1);
        if(adjacent==null) {
            return false;
        }
        return adjacent.contains(node2);
    }

    public LinkedList<String> adjacentNodes(String last) {
        LinkedHashSet<String> adjacent = map.get(last);
        if(adjacent==null) {
            return new LinkedList<String>();
        }
        return new LinkedList<String>(adjacent);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your expected vs actual output?

Comment: Why would it go into `printFavp`?

Comment: what to you mean by " it is not going into favp"?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your effort & time.

Comment: A search for [Deep copy of list](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]deep+copy+of+list) would help you understand why cloning the list worked. Basically, you need to copy the element of the `List` else you're just referencing it and any modification to it will affect the `List`s in `favp`.

Comment: Thank you. to summarize I have just asked how to copy a list returned by a method to a list of list.
Now I have realized that this should be the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add visited to favp you are pushing visited list itself, so if you modify it outside printPath call, it will change. Try cloning visited when adding to favp:

```
favp.add(visited.clone());
```

Comment: This helped though it was just a clue.
favp.add((LinkedList<String>)visited.clone());
The above code is good but it gives warning though.
Thank you John